# Solve for all real $x$: $(3x^2-8x+5)/(4x^2-3x+7) > 0$

Tags: inequality, quadratics

I know how to solve quadratic inequalities but I can't figure out how to solve 
$$\frac{3x^2-8x+5}{4x^2-3x+7} > 0$$ for all real $x$. Help would be appreciated

Comment: Find zeros of the above polynomials and singularities. Then look at what happens in between those points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$4x²-3x+7>0$ since the discriminant is negative and if we evaluate it at 0 for example the result is 7 which is positive. Therefore your inequality is equivalent to $3x^2-8x+5>0$ which is easy to solve.
Note that $$3x^2-8x+5=(x-1)(3x-5)>0\iff x\in(-\infty,1)\cup(\frac53,\infty)$$

Answer (score 1):

Solve the pair of systems $$\begin{cases}3x^2-8x+5>0\\ 4x^2-3x+7>0\end{cases}\lor \begin{cases}3x^2-8x+5<0\\ 4x^2-3x+7<0\end{cases}$$ with your favourite method.

Comment: After solving the two pairs, do I take the union of the solutions?

Comment: Yes ,a union of intersections

Comment: Ahh ok, Got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider two cases:
$$3x^2-8x+5\geq 0$$ and $$4x^2-3x+7>0$$ or
$$3x^2-8x+5\le 0$$ and $$4x^2-3x+7<0$$
The result is given by $$x<1$$ or $$x>\frac{5}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note the denominator has constant sign (for real $x$) since its discriminant is negative and therefore has no real zeroes; by inspection, it is always positive.

So you only need to find where the numerator is positive.

Comment: But how to come to the conclusion that since D<0 for denominator, that it will always yield a positive value? I mean how do you arrive at the conclusion on inspection

Comment: $D=0$ only tells you the sign is constant--in theory it could be either positive or negative. Then you can either note that the sign will match the leading coefficient ($+4$, which is positive), or just test a value (easiest to plug in $x=0$ to see the result is $+7$, which is positive). The leading coefficient test works because for very large $x$ the leading term will dominate.

Comment: If the discriminant is negative you can evaluate you expression at every real number you want e.g 0, the sign of the expression is exactly the sign of $f(0)$. You can also look at the coefficient of $x^2$ if it is positive then the expression is positive, if not it is negative